# Is there a way to limit the width of text in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, size, uitextview

I have UITextView where I need to control where text start and end.

This because I use bubble as background image for UITextView and I need to display the text inside the bubble image.

So far,I have been able to control where text start using:

```
self.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = -10, .y = -10};
```

but I have no clue how to control where text end. Currently, by default  it uses all UITextView width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## define #define TEXT_LENGTH 25 // Whatever your limit is

The `UITextView` calls this method whenever the user types a new character or deletes an existing character.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSUInteger newLength = (textView.text.length - range.length) + text.length;
    if(newLength <= TEXT_LENGTH)
    {
        return YES;
    } else {
        NSUInteger mySpace = TEXT_LENGTH - (textView.text.length - range.length);
        textView.text = [[[textView.text substringToIndex:range.location] 
                                            stringByAppendingString:[text substringToIndex: mySpace]]
                                         stringByAppendingString:[textView.text substringFromIndex:(range.location + range.length)]];
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Use `replacementText`  not `replacementString` in method, so careful with the different between replacementString and replacementText.

Answer (score 1):

Will the bubble grow in height as the text stretches? Or will the bubble be limited to 1 line? Either way, I think you should use a different approach to deal with this problem.

Use `-sizeWithFont:constainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` on an NSString instance to figure out what the size is of the text. If the size is greater then the value allowed by you, stop allowing input (if that's your goal) or increase hight of the bubble and allow text to continue on next line.

You would typically perform these recalculations upon text input, which means you'd implement the UITextViewDelegate method `-textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` according to the above suggestions.

*-- or --*

Just limiting the size of the textView and setting the lineBreakMode & numberOfLines might also be sufficient for your purposes.